# Threading + raw_input in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I've got a Python script that does a bunch of things in a single subthread, and I'd like the main thread to spit out `raw_input("> ")` (to be handled by the main thread), and keep that input on the bottom of the console, while the subthread prints things above. I originally thought I could use something like `print "\b\b" + message + "\n> "` in the subbthread, but that doesn't account for things like characters the user has typed in. So, the console would look something like this:

```
[22:04] Started
[22:06] Some output
[22:06] Some more output
>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Isn't curses made for such things?

Comment: Could be... How would I do this, though?

Comment: Read this: http://docs.python.org/howto/curses.html

Comment: will this only be used in a vt100-like terminal (linux/osx/putty/etc?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the [curses](http://docs.python.org/howto/curses.html) suggestions, you might want to take a look at [*urwid*](http://excess.org/urwid/), a higher-level, more python friendly library for dealing with console output.