# Interrupting raw_input from another thread

Tags: python, multithreading, blocking

I have two threads:

```
printlock = threading.Lock()

# Main thread:
while True:
   if not(printlock.locked()):
      stdin_input = raw_input()
      do_something(stdin_input)

# Listening thread:
while True:
   socket_input = listen_to_socket()
   with printlock:
      print socket_input
```

The behavior now is that once the listening thread receives input it prints stuff that overwrites the raw_input(). The content of raw_input is still there, but it is hidden behind some other output. What I would like to achieve is that when the listening thread receives input, it interrupts the main thread's blocking / waiting for raw_input to finish, so that it just resumes at the top of the while loop.

- It is OK if I loose the current content of the raw_input().
- Solution needs to work only in linux.
- I want to use raw_input instead of directly reading from stdin because I am using the readlines module.

There are several related questions on SO but none really address my problem - they do not provide a way to interrupt the raw_input. I think this should be possible through signals or exceptions, but I have not yet figured out how.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I don't think `raw_input` is that controllable. You'd probably need to implement this yourself, or maybe a third party library has already been created. Also, see [**`curses`**](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Threading + raw\_input in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505450/threading-raw-input-in-python)

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate, and even though the other thread has an accepted answer, I do not consider "have a look at curses" a quality answer that should be accepted. I know curses, and I would prefer not to use it.